# Code browsing for scripts

Tags: scripts, sh

We have `cscope` and `ctags` for .c and .h files.

Are there any code browsing tools for shell scripts (`.sh`)?

Answer (score 0):

`ctags`! `ctags` supports shell scripts:

```
$ ctags rename-windows.sh 
$ cat tags
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.9~svn20110310 //
find_num_files  rename-windows.sh   /^find_num_files ()$/;" f
str_join    rename-windows.sh   /^str_join ()$/;"   f
```

I had only two functions, and both were detected. If your script doesn't have a `.sh` extension, you'll have to `--language-force` it.